# Angular 2: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router

Tags: angular

I get this error in my RC5 app:

> Promise rejection: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router.

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

shared.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [TranslatePipe, DateToStringPipe, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  exports: [TranslatePipe, DateToStringPipe, CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {

    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        FeedbackService,
        CookieService,
        AuthService,
        LoggerService,
        RouteGuard,
        {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json'),
          deps: [Http]
        },
        TranslateService,
        SearchService,
        SharedComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
      ]
    };

  }

}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ SharedModule],
  providers: []
})
export class SharedRootModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent extends SharedComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    _feedbackService: FeedbackService,
    _loggerService: LoggerService,
    _translateService: TranslateService,
    _authService: AuthService,
    _router: Router
) {

    super(
        _feedbackService,
        _loggerService,
        _translateService,
        _authService,
        _router
    );

}
```

and finally shared.component.ts:

```
constructor(
    protected _feedbackService: FeedbackService,
    protected _loggerService: LoggerService,
    protected _translateService: TranslateService, 
    protected _authService: AuthService, 
    protected _router: Router
) {

}
```

I tried using `AppComponent` without the extension from `SharedComponent` like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(){
}
```

but that still produces the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Angular thinks it is not necessary to inject `Router` in the `Module` level, it is reasonable you inject the `Router` after at least one component is loaded. I suspect at least one of your services must be injecting `Router`, which is provided to the loaded `Module`, which causes this error. What you can do is to inject the service that uses the `Router` to the app component, so at least one component is loaded first, and all your sub-components will inherit the service from the app component.