# Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router Angularjs 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I've google a lot for the issue but haven't find any related article or stackoverflow question though there are many question with the same title but different in scenario. I have not been able to require dependencies on the constructor of a service which is why I am getting the this error.

```
Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Bootstrap at least one component before
```

**Note :** If I just `clear the constructor` dependencies defined in the `CustomerService class` then it works like a charm.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private siteService: SiteService) { }
```

AuthService and Site Service Class and It's dependencies are loaded with no problem. Just some sudo facade of AuthService and SiteService Class

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService 
constructor(private http: Http, private storageService: StorageService, 
            private siteService: SiteService, private router: Router) {}


@Injectable()
export class SiteService {
constructor(private http: Http, private storageService: StorageService) {}
```

And also `App Module` `@ngModule` decorator.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    CompanyComponent,
    Step2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularAppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ AuthGuard, AuthService, StorageService, StepsNavigatorGuard, SiteService, CustomerService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Note:** The issue just remains with the `CustomerService`. If I try to remove it from the provider array in `AppModule` or clear it's `constructor` dependencies then the app runs fine.

Any help would be appreciated alot.

Comment: Please add the `@NgModule()` of your root component.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148492/angular-2-bootstrap-at-least-one-component-before-injecting-router

Comment: The suggestion seems to be to inject `AuthService` to `AppComponent`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that does not seems to work.. I've tried loading that in  `AppComponent` aswell

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer cheers.. did it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using angular router version

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0"
```

and tried updating it to

```
"@angular/router": "3.1.0"
```

worked like a charm. :)